# Create or populate a table in python based on other tables

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy

I am new to python/pandas and have a fairly basic question.

I have 2 tables with numerous columns and "ID" as the primary key.

I want to create another table with conditions based on the 2 tables.

For example: Table A, Table B --> Table C

In SQL I would write something like this:

```
create table TableC as select 
a.ID, 
case when b.Field1=1000 and a.Field1=50 then 20 else 0 end as FieldA,
case when b.Field2=15 and a.Field2=100 then 100 else 0 end as FieldB
from TableA a, TableB b
where a.ID=b.ID
order by 1
```

I am struggling to put similar together Table C using python.
I have tried to make a function but I cant seem to include more than 1 table in the function nor create a new table based off multiple tables.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
TableC=TableA.merge(TableB,on='ID')
TableC['FieldA']=np.where((TableC.Field1_x==1000)& (TableC.Field1_y==50),20,0)
TableC['FieldB']=np.where((TableC.Field2_x==15)& (TableC.Field2_y==100),100,0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is it possible to expand this for instance to include "else if"? For example (TableC.Field1_x==1000)& (TableC.Field1_y==50) then 20 else if (TableC.Field1_x==2000)& (TableC.Field1_y==500) then 50 else 0?

Comment: @babz yep ,`np.where((TableC.Field1_x==1000)& (TableC.Field1_y==50),20,np.where((TableC.Field1_x==2000)& (TableC.Field1_y==500),50,0))`

Comment: appreciate it. How about a case below. np.where(TableC.Field1_x==1000 or 800 or 700,20,0)?

Comment: np.where(TableC.Field1_x.isin([1000 , 800 , 700]),20,0) @babz

Comment: last thing. What if I have a condition such as 'first 4 letters of the field'. i.e. np.where(TableC.Field1_x.str[0:4].isin(['ABCD','DEFG']),20,0). Using this syntax gives me an error asking for a .loc but not sure how or where that applies

Comment: @babz TableC['Field1_x'].astype(str).str[0:4].isin(['ABCD','DEFG'])

Comment: The field is already a string and I am still getting the same error. Table['Field3']=np.where(((Table.Field1=='J')&(Table.Field2.astype(str).str[0:4].isin(['JLP10', 'JLP15']))),3,2))) Error:A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @babz aha, so you mean this error code right ? `Table=Table.assign(Field3=np.where(((Table.Field1=='J')&(Table.Field2.astype(str).str[0:4].isin(['JLP10', 'JLP15']))),3,2))) )`

Comment: amazing. It runs now but I am testing it with a dummy field where I have put Field1=J Field2 = 'JLP10'..The code outputs 2 instead of 3. If I remove the .str[0:4] then it outputs 3... any idea why the 0:4 is not working?

Comment: @babz that is all I can do , before you show me the real data

Comment: The data is dummy for now and literally: Col1: 1,2,3 Field1: 'J','Q','S' Field2: 'JLP10A','JLP25A','JLP20A'. When I use the following code I get the output as 2. Table=Table.assign(Field3=np.where(((Table.Field1=='J')&(Table.Field2.astype(str).str[0:4].isin(['JLP10', 'JLP15']))),3,2))) ). When I use the following code I get output as 3. Table=Table.assign(Field3=np.where(((Table.Field1=='J')&(Table.Field2.isin(['JLP10A', 'JLP15']))),3,2))) ). So the code is not reading the 0:4 correctly, but the isin is working since when I remove the 0:4 (and change Field2 to match exactly) the result is 3